# How to present/view an android screen on a macbook pro?

Tags: android, macos

I'm looking for an application and software that i can use in order to present/view my android screen on my mac like the one that google is using on their keynote and presentations. All the actions will be from the mobile phones and the screen on the computer will show what i'm doing on my phone. I'm using Galaxy Nexus with 4.2. I have found the droid at screen but is too slow to update the screen on the computer. Does anyone knows any other application? I prefer an application which is using usb cable but are welcome also solutions using for wifi.

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42491/how-to-remote-view-and-control-your-android-phone/ should work for mac to, and it also enables you to control your phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [MHL to HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link) adapter to output video from your Galaxy Nexus. Android 4.2 on the Galaxy Nexus supports this. You can then use any media card adapter to take HDMI input on your laptop.

Comment: thanks Raghav its a very good idea but i'm using a macbook pro. and i will use the hdmi cable of the projector to show my presentation.

Comment: @GeorgePanayi Even I use a MacBook Pro, and I have a unbranded Media Card that takes HDMI input over USB which I can then open as a stream on my mac in VLC etc. You could try finding a media card that does the same for you, but I can't offer any suggestions as mine is unbranded.

Answer (score 1):

Raghav's answer's the best way I know to do this, however if this is not an option for you, I've used [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc) in the past.

It's a bit slow, but works in a pinch and you don't need to buy anything new.

Comment: i didn't find any adapter that i can used to show the android screen on my computer instead to the projector direct using an HDMI cable. can anyone else has a solution? i want to show the screen from my macbook pro instead of connect it direct to the hdmi cable

Answer (score 0):

Best I have found so far was droid@screen.

It requires a number of steps, downloading, JAVA components, Adroid SDK and other bits, some other tweaking and a JAR file but it *does* work.

It is a bit slow though refreshing the screen via the USB cable.

I'm running Yosemite on a 2 month old macbook air and its a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 phone.

Good luck !